Java Wildfly application - JAX-RS REST annotations not being picked up
I have a Wildfly application that I am deploying/starting within a pod/container. I am trying to add liveness, readiness, and startup probes for my pod. To do this, I am trying to create an endpoint that these probes can hit to determine whether or not the Wildfly application is ready.
The versions of the dependencies I am using are (snippet from my pom):
. . .
  <version.jakarta.jakartaee-api>8.0.0</version.jakarta.jakartaee-api>
  <version.wildfly>26.1.0.Final</version.wildfly>
  <version.wildfly.bootable.jar>7.0.2.Final</version.wildfly.bootable.jar>
  <version.wildfly-jakartaee8>${version.wildfly}</version.wildfly-jakartaee8>
</properties>

For wildfly-jakartaee8, I have the scope set to provided.
I have created an empty class that extends Application from javax.ws.rs.core:
@ApplicationPath("/some-path")
public class RestApplication extends Application {

}

I have then created another class that specifies an endpoint to GET:
@Path("/health")
public class MyResource {
    @GET
    public Response pingMyResource() {
        return Response.ok().entity("My Resource is healthy").build();
    }
}

I believe this should work as it is without the need to update the web.xml as the annotations by themselves should work.
When starting up my JAR/Wildfly application, I don't see anything in the logs related to what I've added here.
Running the following curl command(s) yield the below error message:
curl -vk https://localhost:8443/some-path/health/
curl -vk https://localhost:8443/project-name/some-path/health/
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8443...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8443 (#0)
* ALPN: offers h2,http/1.1
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS alert, handshake failure (552):
* OpenSSL/1.1.1f: error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) OpenSSL/1.1.1f: error:14094410:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert handshake failure

Am I missing some dependencies or do I in fact need to do more configuration?

Your handshake is failing, that has nothing to do with the endpoint. Try port 8080 over a non https connection.
